# cocos2d "There isn't any available platforms" error

Tags: cygwin, installation, cocos2d-js

I just installed cocos2d-js on Windows/cygwin and am trying to run things (moonwarrior sample and a new project) with

```
cocos run -p web
```

Unfortunately I get the error "There isn't any available platforms".  Aside from the incorrect grammar, I can't find out what's gone wrong.  I did download/install for "web only", but I'm trying to run web and it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, The cygwin environment is not supported by `cocos2d console`.

The error message "There isn't any available platforms" just complaint about it.

You might need to change to noncygwin environment.

You could simply open CMD and type in `cocos run -p web`.

Comment: Is there really not a workaround to get 'cocos' to just accept cygwin and then just hope it works? Shouldn't be that different from a Linux shell, hopefully :-)